# Pig is not running in mapreduce mood (hadoop 3.1.1 + pig 0.17.0)

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig, hadoop3

I am very new to Hadoop. My hadoop version is **3.1.1** and pig version is **0.17.0**.

Everything is working as expected by running this script in local mode

**pig -x local**

```
grunt> student = LOAD '/home/ubuntu/sharif_data/student.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as ( id:int, firstname:chararray, lastname:chararray, phone:chararray, city:chararray );
grunt> DUMP student;
```

Result for local mode[image]

But for the same input file and pig script, mapreduce mode is not working successfully.

**pig -x mapreduce**

```
grunt> student = LOAD '/pig_data/student.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS ( id:int, firstname:chararray, lastname:chararray, phone:chararray, city:chararray );
grunt> STORE student INTO '/pig_data/student_out' USING PigStorage (',');
```

OR

```
grunt> student = LOAD 'hdfs://NND1:9000/pig_data/student.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS ( id:int, firstname:chararray, lastname:chararray, phone:chararray, city:chararray );
grunt> STORE student INTO 'hdfs://NND1:9000/pig_data/student_out' USING PigStorage (',');
```

Result for mapreduce mode[image]
OR
[image]
Note: student.txt is uploaded to HDFS successfully.

```
hdfs dfs -ls  /pig_data 
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 ubuntu supergroup     861585 2019-07-12 00:55 /pig_data/en.sahih.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 ubuntu supergroup        234 2019-07-12 12:25 /pig_data/student.txt
```

Even under **grunt** this command returns correct HDFS file name.

```
grunt> fs -cat /pig_data/student.txt
```

- Why is it saying failed to read data when the file exists in that
  path?
- What could be the possible reasons that I am missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not checking locally? You haven't specified HDFS in the URL. Notice how the full HDFS URL is used here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_pig/apache_pig_grunt_shell

Comment: Why  would I need hdfs path as pig can identify it using fs? FYI i have tried with hdfs path too :(

Comment: Does the job run if you point into to the same file stored locally?

Comment: yeah. In local mode, my local files are run successfully. Only problem that it failed in mapreduce mode with errors like this:  *Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the problem is that Pig 0.17 doesn't support Hadoop 3 yet.

The [Apache Pig Releases](https://pig.apache.org/releases.html) states for 0.17:

> 19 June, 2017: release 0.17.0 available
>
> The highlights of this release is the introduction of Pig on Spark
>
> Note:
> This release works with Hadoop 2.X (above 2.7.x)

And JIRA [PIG-5253 - Pig Hadoop 3 support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-5253) is still in progress.

Comment: Thanks for your reference :) . I am confused because it was working in local mode.

Comment: Yeah, local mode just uses the underlying OS's filesystem.

Comment: Same for hive 3.1.1, it does support hadoop 3.1.1 either.    . https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-20022  (just pasting the link here as reference if someone is benefited)